# How do you ignore quotes when creating a dyamic frame in aws glue?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a text file in an S3 Bucket I want to use to create a dynamic frame. A row looks like this:

"0001" "aaaa"

Simple file with two columns. I just wanna make a dynamic frame with two columns with the respective values. How do I exclude the quotes from my dynamic frame?

Comment: is there any char between `"0001""aaaa"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try format=csv and its format options as stated https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html

This will work only if there is one char between two values. That char should be `separator`

Method to create dynamic frame: `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options()`